# Set PHP's open_basedir for all users' public_html via mod_userdir

Tags: php, apache2, open-basedir, apache2-module

I have an Apache 2 web server that allows access to the `public_html` directory for each user via `mod_userdir`, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        # [*] configuration here
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I would like to additionally configure PHP's `open_basedir` directive to forbid file access outside the user's homedir.  For user `jim`, the directive would be

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/jim/"
```

**Question:** Does Apache offer a way to do this through a variable at the spot marked `[*]` above, something like the following?

```
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value open_basedir "${APACHE_CURRENT_DIRECTORY}"
    </Directory>
```

Comment: I guess the above would then use `/home/jim/public_html` instead of `/home/jim`, so I'd have to write something like `"${APACHE_CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/.."`.

Comment: What do you mean by outside of the user home dir? Parent dir, children, or something else? Also, what is APACHE_CURRENT_DIRECTORY?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about mod_php, but this should work. I assume that your APACHE_CURRENT_DIRECTORY variable is supposed to point to the current directory context, so just placing a "." will take care of it (unless mod php doesn't behave). Let me know how it goes.

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
  php_admin_value open_basedir "."
</Directory>
```